# How to specify system property in hadoop except modify hadoop-env.sh?

Tags: java, hadoop, system-properties

I'd like to set system property (not hadoop property) when running hadoop jobs. I found that it's not easy to setting system property.  Even I set the property in shell

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS:-Dproperty=value"
```

It's still not working. The "-D" option of hadoop command line is only for Configuration, not system property. So the "-D" option also not working

Anyone has ideas ? thanks

Comment: Can we see the command you are using to start your job? Are you using a `ToolRunner` or `GenericOptionsParser` at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not simply use `-Dfoo.bar=example` in-line when starting the job via command line, like so:

`hadoop jar example.jar com.example.ExampleTool -Dfoo.bar=example argument`

In order to get at the property in code, use `conf.get("foo.bar");`

---

Now if you genuinely need it to be set as a system property, you can set it at the start of your code using the value you got from Hadoop config like so:

```
String property = conf.get("foo.bar");
System.setProperty("foo.bar", property);
```

Comment: The reason is that I am using a library which need to get system property

Comment: I see, I've edited my answer to a potential solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

The `hadoop` script invoke java class like this

```
exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
```

so, we can pass system-wide property like this:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Dfoo=bar"
```