# pass Hadoop arguments into Java code

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I have an Uber jar that performs some Cascading ETL tasks. The jar is executed like this:

```
hadoop jar munge-data.jar
```

I'd like to pass arguments to the jar when the job is launched, e.g.

```
hadoop jar munge-data.jar -Denv=prod
```

Different credentials, hostnames, etc... will be read from properties files depending on the environment.

This would work if the job were executed `java jar munge-data.jar -Denv=prod`, since the `env` property could be accessed:

```
System.getProperty("env")
```

However, this doesn't work when the jar is executed `hadoop jar ...`.

I saw a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490090/how-to-specify-system-property-in-hadoop-except-modify-hadoop-env-sh) where the answerer states that properties can be accessed using what looks like the org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration class. It wasn't clear to me, from the answer, how the `conf` object gets created. I tried the following and it returned `null`:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
System.out.println(configuration.get("env"));
```

Presumably, the configuration properties need to be read/set.

Can you tell me how I can pass properties, e.g. `hadoop jar [...] -DsomeProperty=someValue`, into my ETL job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Driver class should implement [Tool](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) interface which allow you to use [ToolRunner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html) to run your MapReduce job:

```
public class MRDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to run jobs by following way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new MRDriver(), args);
    System.exit(res);
}
```

It means that all your commannd line parameters parsed by ToolRunner to the current instance of Configuration class.

Assuming you run job from console with following command:

```
hadoop jar munge-data.jar -Denv1=prod1 -Denv2=prod2
```

Then in `run()` method you can get all your arguments from Configuration class:

```
public int run(String args[]) {
    Configuration conf = getConf();

    String env1 = conf.get("env1");
    String env2 = conf.get("env2");

    Job job = new Job(conf, "MR Job");
    job.setJarByClass(MRDriver.class);

    /*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the arguments in two ways. Either using -D option or using configuration. But you can only use -D option when you implement Tool interface. If not then you have to set the configuration variables by conf.set.

**Passing parameters using -D:**

```
hadoop jar example.jar com.example.driver -D property=value /input/path /output/path
```

**Passing parameters using Configuration:**

```
Configuration conf=new Configuration();
conf.set("property","value");
Job job=new Job(conf);
```

Note: All the configuration variables have to be set before initializing Job class